# Is document.documentElement always defined and always the html element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'd like to modify the `<html>` element from a script that's inside the `<head>` element of an HTML page. I don't need to access/modify any of `<html>`'s children, just `<html>` itself.

Would that script in some cases need to wait for `DOMContentLoaded`, or will `document.documentElement` ***always*** be defined? Will `document.documentElement` ***always*** be the `<html>` element?

For example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.documentElement.style.foo = 'bar';
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- ... -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's always defined.

> The documentElement property returns the documentElement of the
>   document, as an Element object. For HTML documents the returned object is the `<html>` element. This property is read-only.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_document_documentelement.asp

While `document.body` can be null if script is running from `<head>` tag and page is not fully loaded, `<html>` element is always present in html document.

Comment: What are you quoting? Please cite the source.

Comment: W3schools is [not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280478/1541563) an [authoritative source](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4976/73672).

Answer (score 8):

This is quite trivial to test:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      console.log(document.documentElement instanceof HTMLHtmlElement);
      console.log(document.documentElement === document.querySelector('html'));
    </script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

But to quote [the W3C DOM4 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#document-element):

> ```
> [Constructor,
>  Exposed=Window]
> interface Document : Node {
>   ...
>   readonly attribute Element? documentElement;
>   ...
> };
> ```
>
> The *document element* of a [document](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-document) is the [element](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-element) whose [parent](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-tree-parent) is that [document](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-document), if it exists, and null otherwise.
>
> > *Note: Per the [node tree](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-node-tree) constraints, there can only be one such [element](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-element).*

<sup>This specification exists verbatim in [the DOM Standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#document-element) as well.</sup>

So technically it *is* nullable, as you can confirm here:

```js
let doc = new Document();
console.log(doc.documentElement);
```

However, for *your purposes*, as you're using the `document` that a `<script>` belongs to, it will never be `null` in that case.

Comment: It is trivially tested in my browser, but I wanted to ensure that it wouldn't vary in other browsers – whether it was standardized. The second part of your answer addresses that. Thanks!

Comment: To be clear, it’s worth noting that `new Document()` doesn’t create a new *HTML* document — and as far as actually creating an HTML document: with any scripted way you use to do it, it’ll always be created with an `html` element as the document element. For example, using `document.implementation.createHTMLDocument()` will give you a document with an `html` document element. And you can always set the document element of any HTML document to null, using `document.documentElement.remove()` or whatever — but of course any way you do is necessarily gonna result in it becoming an empty document.